# How to select for td class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, preventdefault

I'm having trouble selecting for an element on my DOM.

How do you select for all links of the td class trash can?

```
<td class="trash_can">
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete Greek Theater at U.C. Berkeley?" href="/promotions/2/places/46">
<img id="trash_can" src="http://test.dev/images/trash.png?1305741883" alt="Trash">
```

The following code does nothing and is not working:

```
$(function(){
  $('.trash_can').live("click", function(event) {
    console.log('Clicked Delete');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.trash_can` selects your `td`, not its `a`. You want to apply the event handler to the `a` element.

```
$(function(){
  $('.trash_can a').live("click", function(event) {
    console.log('Clicked Delete');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for looking right and being the most complete, deleted mine as its a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

you need to a the anchor tag to the selector

```
$(function(){
  $('.trash_can a').live("click", function(event) {
    console.log('Clicked Delete');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Also you should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of live()

Example:

```
$(".trash_can").delegate("a", "click", function(){
        console.log('Clicked Delete');
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to select the links themselves rather than the td.

```
 $(function(){
   $('.trash_can a').live("click", function(event) {
     console.log('Clicked Delete');
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```